# Largest $R$ value in domian $0<|z-1|<R$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Determine the largest real number $R>0$ such that the Laurent series of $$f(z)=\frac1{z-1} +\frac2{z-i}$$ about $z=1$ converges for $0<|z-1|<R$.

The singularities are $1$ and $i$. But in the region of the domain, $1$ is not inside the region so we should leave the first fraction how it is right?

Should find a taylor or Laurent expansion of the other fraction? It seems impossible to find a taylor of it but I think that is the one we need to find since the region is a circle excluding the point $1$ with radius $R$.

And then how would we find $R$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Laurent Series of this function will be analytic on an annulus with a hole at $1$ and which does not contain $i$. So,
$R=|1-i|=\sqrt2$.

Comment: I knew that was the answer... But this was a $4$ mark question, and we didn't have to expand anything?

Comment: Is that all we have to do to get full marks?

Comment: Well I'm that would be up to whoever is grading this. Does the question ask you to find the series?

Comment: I literally wrote word for word on the main post, so no... But what would the series actually be? Because I cant seem to find a taylor series of $2/(z-i)$...

Comment: I'll expand my answer.

Comment: You could calculate it directly from the definition.

Comment: Thanks please do expand your answer. Would really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry something's come up. It's not difficult to expand $2/(z-i)$ to a power series about $1$ directly from the definition.

Comment: But it has to be for $|z-1|<1$ which I cant seem to get... I did all the plus $1-1$ stuff but that $i$ is making it impossible.

Comment: $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!}(z-1)^n$.